# Android browsers wont open PDF in Browser when Content-Disposition is set in Header

Tags: php, android, apache, pdf, content-disposition

On my Apache webserver i can server PDF files directly in the Browser with a simple Anchor link like:

```
<a href="myfolder/mysample.pdf">Click to display PDF</a>
```

This Works fine.

Now, i've got a lot of PDF's i want to Protect. So i moved them all outside the Web folder, and are serving them through a PHP download program - i called it download.php

To be sure that the pdf files are not downloaded as "download.php" i have to set the Content-Disposition Header to 'inline;filename="mysample.pdf"'. Inline because i want to open it in the Browser.

No Problem, all works fine. the files are downloading fine on Windows and Apple Browsers and are displayed IN the Browser, just like when its served directly from the Apache Server.

But my download.php doesn't work with Android Browsers... It's always just downloaded but not opened in the browser. You have to find the file in your messages and open it separately. When served directly from Apache it IS opened in the Browser.

It seems to be connected with Content-Disposition Header im setting in my download.php, because this is the only difference i see in the headers when download direct and indirect.

Anybody had the same problem?

Thanks
Per

Comment: IIRC, Android default browser doesn't have PDF reading capabilities, at least on Android < 4.1.2, can't vouch for later versions

Comment: Im using Android > 4.1.2, and it works, as long as I link directly to the files. My Download.php works fine on IPhone.

Comment: Are you prompted to open it in Acrobat or Polaris?

Comment: When i download it Directly from Apache, yes i'm Prompted. But not over my Download.php, the file is simply downloaded - i must open it myself. When i compare the headers sent from Apache and my Program, the main difference is the Content-Disposition header i am setting in Download.php